# hello i would like to make a filter by date with ajax using checkboxes to retrieve my offers in my laravel database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have three possible date values: 'today', '7 days' and '30 days'. How to convert these values and pass them in Ajax.

This is my HTML code

```
  <div class="panel panel-default panel-faq">
        <!-- panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div  class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordion-two">
                    <h4>Date Posted <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></h4>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- panel-heading -->

        <div id="accordion-two" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <!-- panel-body -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <label for="today"><input type="checkbox" name="today" class="filtreDate" value="today" id="today"> Today</label>
                <label for="7-days"><input type="checkbox" name="7-days" class="filtreDate" value="7-days" id="7-days"> 7 days</label>
                <label for="30-days"><input type="checkbox" name="30-days" class="filtreDate" value="30-days" id="30-days"> 30 days</label>
            </div><!-- panel-body -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my javascript function

```
 $(".filtreDate").click(function () {
       var date = [];
       $(".filtreDate").each(function () {
           if($(this).is(":checked")) {
               date.push($(this).val());
           }
       });
       finalDate = date.toString();
       console.log(finalDate);
      //the ajax code here
   });
```

how i cant convert 7-days to use it in my database query like

```
$filtreDate = Job::with(['Category', 'Ville', 'Type', 'Salaire', 'User', 'Entreprise', 'Level'])
            ->where('created', explode(',', $result))
            ->where('confirmed', 1)
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(5)
```

Please I need help

Comment: may helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/39859483/3256489

Answer (score 0):

i have solve my problem with the library Carbon.

```
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <label for="today"><input type="checkbox" name="today" class="filtreDate" value="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') }}" id="today"> Today</label>
                                        <label for="7-days"><input type="checkbox" name="7-days" class="filtreDate" value="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')->subWeeks(1) }}" id="7-days"> 7 days</label>
                                        <label for="30-days"><input type="checkbox" name="30-days" class="filtreDate" value="{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')->subDays(30) }}" id="30-days"> 30 days</label>
                                    </div><!-- panel-body -->
```